# Issue with Node.js Deployment on Render: Unable to Locate index.js

Tags: express, deployment, backend, production, react-fullstack

Smooth deployment of the back-end app without encountering errors related to the location of the index.js file.

Actual Behavior:

Node.js reports an error, stating it is unable to find the index.js file at the expected location /opt/render/project/src/index.js.  Here's a snippet of my package.json file:

```json
{
  "name": "smart-brain-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A full-stack application for image recognition using Clarifai API, built with Express.js and PostgreSQL.",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  /* ... other properties ...*/
} 
json


Error Messages:

The application is trying to execute `node index.js`. Node.js is unable to locate the index.js file at the expected location /opt/render/project/src/index.js.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

1. Checked the specified path to ensure the index.js file exists.
2. Verified the correct directory structure in the deployment settings.
3. Confirmed that the index.js file is included in the repository.

Additional Information:

- Node.js version: 21.3.0
- Project structure: 

smart-brain-api
│
├── controllers
│   ├── image.js
│   ├── profile.js
│   ├── register.js
│   └── signin.js
│
├── node_modules
│
├── package-lock.json
│
├── package.json
│
└── server.js

Request for Assistance:

Seeking guidance on resolving this deployment issue. Any insights into why Node.js is having trouble locating the index.js file during deployment on Render would be greatly appreciated. Identify the Correct Entry Point could be the issue. I do not have an index.js for my backend server. And as provided above you will see I used server.js as my current Entry Point.
```